# How can promise chains assert that which value is from which return value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, electron, chain

I'm currently studying Electron in Action. I'm learning JavaScript on-the-go and this didn't come up in google so I'd thought I'd ask it in here. Imagine we have this code:

```js
newLinkForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = newLinkUrl.value;
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(parseResponse)
    .then(findTitle)
    .then(title => storeLink(title, url))
    .then(clearForm);
});
```

in the first, and the fourth ring of the chain, we've gave a name to the return value of the zeroth, and the third function. But what if there are more than one return values? Do we create a list? Can we call two functions in a promise chain as in:

```js
then(returnvalue1=>funct1, returnvalue2=>funct2)
```

Can we do that? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Check the mdn docs on [Promise#then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).  A promise only returns one value, but you can of course return an array of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second `then` argument is reserved for error handler, `then(returnvalue1=>funct1, returnvalue2=>funct2)` isn't a correct way ti handle return values.

`then` callback receives the only one return value as a parameter, a value that previous `then` callback returns.

In case values from different `then` need to be used together, they should be either passed through entire promise chain as array or object value and destructured:

```
promise
.then(foo => {
   const bar = 'bar';
   return [foo, bar];
 })
.then(([foo, bar]) => {
  // can access both foo and bar
})
```

Or `then` should be nested to have access to the scope where necessary value is available:

```
promise
.then(foo => {
   const bar = 'bar';

   return Promise.resolve(bar);
   .then(bar => {
     // can access both foo and bar
   })
 })
```

This is one of the problems that `async..await` solves.

Answer (score 1):

A promise only has a single resolved value, so a `.then()` handler is only ever passed a single argument.

If you want to resolve a promise with multiple values, then you would typically wrap them in an array or an object and the single resolved value would be the array or the object.

You could use destructuring to then easily reference the multiple values wrapped in the object or array.

Example:

```
Promise.resolve([1,2]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);     // logs [1,2]
    return result;           // pass the array on to the next step
}).then(([a, b]) => {          // use destructuring to get the two items out of the array
   console.log(a); 
   console.log(b);
});
```

---

What you proposed like this:

```
.then(returnvalue1=>funct1, returnvalue2=>funct2)
```

is something entirely different.  Here you're passing two functions to a `.then()` as in `.then(f1, f2)` (or that looks like what you're trying to do).  When you pass a second function to `.then()` that second function is a reject handler (like a `.catch()` handler) and it's only called if the promise rejects and the argument would be the rejection reason.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.